# Store positions/locations in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to have an animation that is controlled by Geometry nodes. I have a boolean input attribute marking whether to apply the geometry nodes transformation: if the node is on, I would like to move the geometry to some pre-specified position.

How can I store the new position inside the geometry nodes? I tried duplicating the object and passing the new one through Object Info, but I wasn't able to get the position of the new object, neither through location (which contains the local transformation, not the global position) nor by manipulating the actual geometry of the other object (likely as I am not able to connect that geometry to the output, as this is another object now).

Is there some easier way to store extra information for a given object to be used in geometry nodes? I found these [id keys](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/release_notes/v2_0/id_keys/), but I think they got removed in geometry nodes.
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot or two or diagrams about your setup and what you're trying to achieve ? Currently I have a bit of trouble understanding what exactly happens. Also Animation Nodes and Geometry Nodes are two separate projects, and they share almost no features together apart from being node-based.

Comment: Added a screenshot. In short, I would like to move my object to some pre-defined position (without changing any relations between vertices, just like a regular move by G) through the geometry nodes.

Comment: @sygi You can use the Transform node for wholesale movement like G in Object Mode, instead of Set Position. So, that's easy, but from your question I got the impression that you'd like to know where an object created is in World coordinates? If so this might help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/257886/world-coordinates-in-geometry-nodes/257989

Comment: Thank you, transform works fine, but yes, I need to somehow pass the information about the target location to geometry nodes. The answer to that question (which recalculates origin of a different object) is one answer, thank you!

I am still wondering though: is there no simpler way?

Comment: Sorry for being slow, but could you paint a clearer picture for us please. You have an object A (the one with the geometry node), and an Object B, which is an external object. Do you also have an Object C, which is created inside the geometry nodes modifier of Object A? And you wanna move which object where?  Did you try the "Relative" mode of Object Info?

Comment: Ideally, I have object A, and some goal position G (represented in world coordinates), and I want to move A to G. To achieve that goal, I duplicated A and moved it to G: this is object B.

The answer above requires me to calcualate a mean position of the vertices in A and B and move based on that; that sounds like a lot of work to pass the target position.

Comment: But as I will be doing this transformation multiple times, I don't want to hardcode G in geometry nodes, but rather keep another copy of the objects in the target position, or make a snapshot saying "this is position G, use it later", and then move the objects to their starting positions.

Comment: maybe you could store the position in a [single mesh](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6wio26t8qqym3l/info_vertex.blend?dl=1) in the form of vertices..? or store your [reference objects](https://www.dropbox.com/s/azl2tzixqlai78j/info_empties.blend?dl=1) inside a collection... both are simple solutions at least for location info

Comment: @sygi, if this topic is still pending, maybe, you could explain step by step, what you are trying to achieve. I did not unterstand enough, to give you an answer. Should the GN animate the movement to the target position? Or should GN only set the position to the target. If it should be animated, should this be based on frames or time? What do you want to do with the stored position?
Do you simply want to set the position of an object to the one of another object if a boolean is true? This is what I understood from your first paragraph. But the rest of this thread does not sound like that.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, Andre. I feel like my mental model for using GN improved, and the question doesn't make that much sense for me anymore: I wanted to have an extra attribute on the object itself to allow holding a separate position, to be able to blend between two positions without creating extra objects. Now I see that storing the extra positions in separate objects seems like the way to go. I voted to close the question.

Comment: I also have the exact same issue/question. For my use-case I want to create an attractor and a boid and have the cube move toward the attractor every frame. In order to do this I need to re-evaluate the vector/distance based on the boids current position. I tried what was shown in the above screenshot, but that doesn't result in giving you the boid's current position. The question is - how do we get the current position as we update it with a translate node

Comment: @sygi It would be great of you to write a short answer to this and mark it as "Accepted Answer" so that this question shows up as solved. Thank you!